# Is CUDA not compatible with Nvidia 440 driver?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

Today I upgraded my Nvidia drivers to version 440 (from 430). Then I probably did something wrong and I uninstalled CUDA (or it was removed by the system, I don't really remember).

I installed the cuda-toolkit by running `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` but the `$CUDA` directory is almost empty: all it contains is a `samples` directory, which includes the pre-compiled samples. There's no source code, no documentation, no libraries, etc. in that directory like it was used to be.

I followed the instructions described at https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal, but when I ran `sudo apt install cuda`, this is what I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libnvidia-common-440
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cuda-command-line-tools-10-1 cuda-compiler-10-1 cuda-cudart-10-1
  cuda-cudart-dev-10-1 cuda-cufft-10-1 cuda-cufft-dev-10-1 cuda-cuobjdump-10-1
  cuda-cupti-10-1 cuda-curand-10-1 cuda-curand-dev-10-1 cuda-cusolver-10-1
  cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1 cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1
  cuda-demo-suite-10-1 cuda-documentation-10-1 cuda-driver-dev-10-1
  cuda-drivers cuda-gdb-10-1 cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-1 cuda-libraries-10-1
  cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 cuda-license-10-1 cuda-memcheck-10-1
  cuda-misc-headers-10-1 cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-npp-dev-10-1 cuda-nsight-10-1
  cuda-nsight-compute-10-1 cuda-nsight-systems-10-1 cuda-nvcc-10-1
  cuda-nvdisasm-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1
  cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1 cuda-nvml-dev-10-1 cuda-nvprof-10-1 cuda-nvprune-10-1
  cuda-nvrtc-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1 cuda-nvtx-10-1 cuda-nvvp-10-1
  cuda-runtime-10-1 cuda-samples-10-1 cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1
  cuda-toolkit-10-1 cuda-tools-10-1 cuda-visual-tools-10-1 libcublas-dev
  libcublas10 libnvidia-cfg1-418 libnvidia-common-418 libnvidia-compute-418
  libnvidia-decode-418 libnvidia-encode-418 libnvidia-fbc1-418
  libnvidia-gl-418 libnvidia-ifr1-418 libxmu-dev libxmu-headers
  nsight-compute-2019.4.0 nsight-systems-2019.3.7 nvidia-compute-utils-418
  nvidia-dkms-418 nvidia-driver-418 nvidia-kernel-common-418
  nvidia-kernel-source-418 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-418
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418
Recommended packages:
  libnvidia-compute-418:i386 libnvidia-decode-418:i386
  libnvidia-encode-418:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-418:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-418:i386
  libnvidia-gl-418:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnvidia-cfg1-440 libnvidia-compute-440 libnvidia-compute-440:i386
  libnvidia-decode-440 libnvidia-decode-440:i386 libnvidia-encode-440
  libnvidia-encode-440:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-440 libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386
  libnvidia-gl-440 libnvidia-gl-440:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-440
  libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-440 nvidia-dkms-440
  nvidia-driver-440 nvidia-kernel-common-440 nvidia-kernel-source-440
  nvidia-utils-440 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda-10-1 cuda-command-line-tools-10-1 cuda-compiler-10-1 cuda-cudart-10-1
  cuda-cudart-dev-10-1 cuda-cufft-10-1 cuda-cufft-dev-10-1 cuda-cuobjdump-10-1
  cuda-cupti-10-1 cuda-curand-10-1 cuda-curand-dev-10-1 cuda-cusolver-10-1
  cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1 cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1
  cuda-demo-suite-10-1 cuda-documentation-10-1 cuda-driver-dev-10-1
  cuda-drivers cuda-gdb-10-1 cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-1 cuda-libraries-10-1
  cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 cuda-license-10-1 cuda-memcheck-10-1
  cuda-misc-headers-10-1 cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-npp-dev-10-1 cuda-nsight-10-1
  cuda-nsight-compute-10-1 cuda-nsight-systems-10-1 cuda-nvcc-10-1
  cuda-nvdisasm-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1
  cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1 cuda-nvml-dev-10-1 cuda-nvprof-10-1 cuda-nvprune-10-1
  cuda-nvrtc-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1 cuda-nvtx-10-1 cuda-nvvp-10-1
  cuda-runtime-10-1 cuda-samples-10-1 cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1
  cuda-toolkit-10-1 cuda-tools-10-1 cuda-visual-tools-10-1 libcublas-dev
  libcublas10 libnvidia-cfg1-418 libnvidia-common-418 libnvidia-compute-418
  libnvidia-decode-418 libnvidia-encode-418 libnvidia-fbc1-418
  libnvidia-gl-418 libnvidia-ifr1-418 libxmu-dev libxmu-headers
  nsight-compute-2019.4.0 nsight-systems-2019.3.7 nvidia-compute-utils-418
  nvidia-dkms-418 nvidia-driver-418 nvidia-kernel-common-418
  nvidia-kernel-source-418 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-utils-418
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nvidia-settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nvidia driver will support multiple Cuda Versions:
Use 'nvidia-smi' to look for the 'highest' cuda version you can support.

you can install multiple cuda versions on your system (download and install from nvidia), but as you go through the install process, do not (uncheck) the Nvidia Driver for older Cuda versions.

For example:  run nvidia-smi and you see you can support up to 10.2 Cuda.

You can install cuda 9 or 10.1, 10.0 into /usr/local by downloading/accesing it from Nvidia.

To use the version of Cuda of your choice modify your $PATH, and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I will point to a search of (cuda, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH) and this blog post for more info:

https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/03/21/using-nvidia-gpu-within-docker-container.html

Kudos to all of those that came before me.